# Maven can't find JSON dependency

Tags: java, json, maven, dependencies, bazel

I'm using Bazel to build my Java program, however whenever I try this command I get the following error:

`bazel run //examples:Test`

```
/Users/seriouslyg0e/Desktop/jazzer/examples/BUILD.bazel:16:22: no such target '@maven//:com_googlecode_json-simple': target 'com_googlecode_json-simple' not declared in package '' defined by /private/var/tmp/_bazel_seriouslyg0e/e98dbf4629f0c8d44a5082fd7d505b2d/external/maven/BUILD and referenced by '//examples:Test'
```

I'm trying to use the JSON library here:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple/1.1.1

and my BAZEL.build file looks like this:

```
java_fuzz_target_test(
    name = "Test",
    srcs = [
        "src/main/java/com/examples/Test.java",
    ],
    tags = ["manual"],
    target_class = "com.example.Test",
    deps = [
        "@maven//:com_googlecode_json-simple",
    ],
)
```

Any ideas why this error is occurring?

The packages I'm using in my code are:

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does Bazel use Central repository?

Comment: Does your WORKSPACE file have maven install setup from `rules_jvm_external`?

Also, `@maven//:com_googlecode_json-simple` might be `@maven//:com_googlecode_json_simple` instead (all underscores).

Answer (score 0):

In your `WORKSPACE` file adjust `maven_install` to include json-simple in artifacts:

```
load("@rules_jvm_external//:repositories.bzl", "rules_jvm_external_deps")
rules_jvm_external_deps()
load("@rules_jvm_external//:setup.bzl", "rules_jvm_external_setup")
rules_jvm_external_setup()
load("@rules_jvm_external//:defs.bzl", "maven_install")

maven_install(
    name = "maven",
    artifacts = [
        "com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:aar:1.1.1",
    ],
    fetch_sources = True,
    repositories = [
        "https://maven.google.com",
        "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2",
    ],
    version_conflict_policy = "pinned",
)
```

...the `dep` label in your `BUILD` file should then be `@maven//:com_googlecode_json_simple_json_simple`:

```
java_fuzz_target_test(
    name = "Test",
    srcs = [
        "src/main/java/com/examples/Test.java",
    ],
    tags = ["manual"],
    target_class = "com.example.Test",
    deps = [
        "@maven//:com_googlecode_json_simple_json_simple",
    ],
)
```